# Performing sum per row based on conditions SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I wanted to know how I can perform a sum per row based on conditions for the columns using SQL (I'm new to SQL).

For example, I have this table:

```
ID  Col_1  Col_2  Col_3 ...  
1     L      L      L   ...  
2     L      Q      Q   ... 
3     L      L      Q   ... 
4     Q      Q      L   ...
```

The result that I'm looking for is:

```
ID  count_L  count_Q
1     3        0
2     1        2
3     2        1
4     1        2
```

I'm not sure on how I should approach this. Doing this using `Count` function if my table was transposed would be easier (I think) but performing the query in the way my data is organized is tricky for me. I think I need nested SQL statements and join them using `UNION` but not sure how to do it.

I wasn't able to find similar questions/solutions elsewhere. Would appreciate some help!

Comment: How many columns do you have. Is the data always L or Q?

Comment: Well the format of the data isn't conducive to normal aggregation; you would have to unpivot the data first so that you have a ID, colName and value; then use conditional aggregration.  Or you could just use if statements for each column but that's alot of writing.

Comment: @CResults I can have more than 2 columns but I do have a set number of columns therefore it can potentially be hard coded if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iif()` and `+`:

```
select id,
       (iif(col_1 = "L" , 1, 0) + iif(col_2 = "L" , 1, 0) + iif(col_3 = "L" , 1, 0) ) as count_l,
       (iif(col_1 = "Q" , 1, 0) + iif(col_2 = "Q" , 1, 0) + iif(col_3 = "Q" , 1, 0) ) as count_q
from t;
```